# Creating custom key paths iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a multiuser application and an array of dictionary for keeping information of each user. Each dictionary contains info of one user. For example I have following keys in per user Dictionaries.

> `userId`
>
> `settings` Within settings I have another Dictionary with keys `musicVolume` and `language`

I use these keys with the following code

```
 [settingsInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"musicVolume"];
```

Now these keysName strings like `@"musicVolume"` were getting spread all over my code. So I decided to make a singleton UtilityClass that i could use to fetch the strings. Now code looks like

```
UtilityClass* shared = [UtilityClass sharedInstance]
[settingsInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:shared.musicVolume];
```

but what I want to do is i.e. music volume with a different keyPath

```
[settingsInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:shared.settings.musicVolume];
```

One way i could do it is by creating a struct or a class for settings and then keeping `musicVolume` with in it. But I was wondering if there is way to do it without creating the class or strict. Directly creating a variable with our own keyPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can opt for const, #define, enum. But the best way in Dictionary that you are using.

Comment: I used #define since i could not figure out a more convenient way. I was able to get code completion and I put it in my UtlityClass Header file so it was available everywhere

Answer (score 0):

`NSString *const kSettingsMusicVolume = @"musicVolume";`
With that declaration you will be able to use `kSettingsMusicVolume` and also get code completion.

You can event `hide` the declaration in the .m file if you place this in the .h file.
`extern NSString *const kSettingsMusicVolume;`

The advantage of this is
1. Code completion
2. If you want to change the actual key, you just need to do it at one place.

`[settingsInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:kSettingsMucicVolume];`